# how to handle UNICODE characters in cherrypy-sqlalchemy-mysql application?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, unicode, sqlalchemy, cherrypy

I am using `cherrypy` along with `sqlalchemy-mysql` as backend. I would like to know the ways of dealing with UNICODE strings in `cherrypy` web application. One brute-force way would be to convert all string coming in as parameters into `UNICODE` (and then decoding them to `UTF-8`) before storing them to database. But I was wondering if there is any standard way of handling `UNICODE` characters in a web application. I tried cherrypy's `tools.encode` but it doesn't seem to work for me (may be I haven't understood it properly yet). Or may be there are standard python libraries to handle `UNICODE`s which I could just import and use. What ways should I look for?

Comment: What's wrong with `tools.encode`? Note there is also `tools.decode`.

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy provides Unicode or UnicodeText for your purposes.
Also don't forget about `u'text'`